# Stored Procedure to loop through values and insert into table?

Tags: sql-server

I have the below query doing exactly what I need it to do for a single part number. The problem is that I have a MAIN table that has a several part numbers and I want to update all of them with this query. I'm thinking a stored procedure is the way to go here, but I'm not sure how to properly loop it through all of the part numbers on the table.

In my head, what makes the most sense logically is to do a While loop starting at Row 1 of the MAIN table, grabbing the PartNumber of the first row, then increasing the index at the end of the loop until it has read the last record. But I'm not sure how to do that in TSQL. Google is less than helpful.

```
DECLARE @ID Int
DECLARE @PartNum VarChar(10)
DECLARE @TopJob Int

SET @PartNum = '12345678'
SET @ID = (SELECT TOP(1) CountQty FROM dbo.OSR_MAIN WHERE PartNumber=@PartNum)

SET @TopJob = (
SELECT Brdcst_Nbr
  FROM dbo.Available_PerPart
  WHERE PartNumber = @PartNum
  ORDER BY Brdcst_Nbr 
  OFFSET (@ID) ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
  )

  PRINT @ID
  PRINT @PartNum
  PRINT @TopJob
  
UPDATE dbo.OSR_MAIN SET dbo.OSR_MAIN.TopJob=@TopJob WHERE [PartNumber]=@PartNum;
```

Below is the objective:

So for the below example of information, what's the best way to display the below metrics:

| Part_Number | Max_Job |
| --- | --- |
| 11111111 | a10 |
| 22222222 | a9 |

Using the below data...

The actual situation is much more complicated, but this is the current hangup I'm having in the simplest way I can explain it.

Main:

| Part_Number | Qty_Onhand | Last_Shipped |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11111111 | 4 | a3 |
| 22222222 | 2 | a6 |

Orders:

| OrderNum | Part_Num |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | 11111111 |
| a2 | 22222222 |
| a3 | 11111111 |
| a4 | 11111111 |
| a5 | 11111111 |
| a6 | 22222222 |
| a7 | 22222222 |
| a8 | 11111111 |
| a9 | 22222222 |
| a10 | 11111111 |

Comment: Looping or using a cursor is never the correct solution in SQL for 99% of cases, simply join the tables and perform a single update. Some sample data and desired results would help you get an answer.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do based on partial code attempt. Adding sample data and desired outcome as text would help clarify.

Comment: I won't be able to share sample data. I like to keep my job lol. That was the problem with my last post on this same topic. But suffice it to say that this is one of the rare times that set based logic won't work. I've worked with set based logic for many years and never had a situation like this.

Comment: So I have a master table of parts that I want to track. The part numbers are my primary key so no duplicates part numbers can accidentally be added, and it is small. Less than 50 parts will ever be in there max. So on the above code, I need to step through all the part numbers in the "PartNumber" column of the master table.

Comment: Sample data doesn't mean real data. It means *example* data that illustrates your issue. Make it up.

Comment: I'm going to edit the post with sample data used from my last post.

Comment: The issue is that the query will have different data for each of the lines of the master table which is why I believe that set based logic won't work in this case. When I put some sort of constraint, or filter, it applies specifically for all parts in the table, and each line with be calculated slightly differently dependent on what the count values are, and other circumstances. And I'm unsure of how to setup a loop in the most efficient way.

Comment: Obviously the data in the edit is not realistic. But the objective is the exactly the same.